# Can't get location detail from bing map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bing-api, bing-maps

I'm using bing map for getting location from latitude and longitude value.

this is the code for getting location detail.

```
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/51.5063249319792,-0.127144753932953?key=Mybingkey
```

It results:

```
{"authenticationResultCode":"ValidCredentials","brandLogoUri":"http:\/\/dev.virtualearth.net\/Branding\/logo_powered_by.png","copyright":"Copyright Â© 2013 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.","resourceSets":[{"estimatedTotal":0,"resources":[]}],"statusCode":200,"statusDescription":"OK","traceId":"a5c5302525354c90a6d265121d5634b2|SINM001004|02.00.183.2300|SINMSNVM000146"}
```

It returns only empty value even I use new bing key. Why its happen.Any one please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this again. This works fine. Note that you don't need 12 decimal places. 5 decimal places has an accuracy of about a meter. All the other decimal places just increase the chance of the query being confused as an address. See this list of tips and tricks for the Bing Maps REST services: http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2013/02/14/bing-maps-rest-service-tips-amp-tricks.aspx